# Customized workflow does not appear on the website

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-workflow

I created a workflow in sharepoint designer whiwh is associated to a list. I've published it but it doesn't appear on the site, even when I try to add it through the parameters of the site.

I've just strated using sharepoint and sharepoint designer and I am working on it after another developper.

Why isn't the workflow appearing?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where are you expecting to see it?

If you want to see it as an option for users to initiate then you have to make sure the start option is set to "Allow this workflow to be manually started from an item"

If you want to check it is attached to the list go to the list's settings and select workflow settings. You will see the name but you won't be able to edit the workflow from SharePoint because it was created in Designer.